# find similar IP in java using java.util.regex.Pattern

Tags: java, regex

I am trying to find similar IP using `java.util.regex.Pattern` in java.

```
String ipAddr = "192.168.112.33";
Pattern PRIVATE_ADDRESS_PATTERN = Pattern.compile("192.168.(.*?).33", Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE);
String IPaddress = PRIVATE_ADDRESS_PATTERN.matcher(ipAddr).toString();
```

It is not working for me. Where is my mistake?

Comment: What means `It is not working`?

Comment: Pattern matches not happing. Sorry for my poor english

Comment: What is the expected Output?

Comment: Thanks @Jens for your time. I confusing with Pattern and matches.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why you simply don't make :

```
String ipAddr = "192.168.112.33";

//If your pattern match with your String then it is correct else it is not
if (ipAddr.matches("192\\.168\\.(.*?)\\.33")) {
    System.out.println("CORRECT");
} else {
    System.out.println("NOT CORRECT");
}
```

Like @lathspell said in the comment you have to escape the dot (.) with `\\.`

Comment: Remember that "." in a RegEx means "any character". You better escape the dots with "\\."

Comment: oop this is correct, thank you i totally forgot that i already edit it @lathspell

Answer (score 0):

A more correct matcher would be the following:

```
Pattern IP_PATTERN = Pattern.compile("192\\.168\\.(\\d{1,3})\\.33");
```

This way you would only match numbers in there and not letters, for instance. According to further use cases, you may want to refine your number matcher to make sure it matches only in the range `0-255`:

```
String IP_PATTERN_PART = "(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|1[0-9][0-9]|[1-9][0-9]|[0-9]?)";
Pattern IP_PATTERN = Pattern.compile("192\\.168\\.("+IP_PATTERN_PART+")\\.33");
```

Also, if you are sure you will never get anything else than an IP (meaning no enclosing text), you may want to use the start and end delimiters:

```
Pattern IP_PATTERN = Pattern.compile("^192\\.168\\.(\\d{1,3})\\.33$");
```

Then, once you've decided which pattern to use, you'll have to use it this way:

```
Matcher matcher = IP_PATTERN.matcher(candidate);
String otherIP = null;
if (matcher.matches()) {
  matcher.find();
  otherIP = matcher.group(1);
}
```